# ftp user permissions for a directly folder Ubuntu 18.04 VSFTPD

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I want to create an ftp `newuser` that will get access to another user (`root`).

Example of `root` tree structure:

```
root
├── Image
├── server
│   ├── reamder.txt
│   └── start-server
│       ├── start.sh
│       └── text.txt
└── Videos
```

I want to access the `root` user to the `start-server` folder when I open the `newuser` via ftp.

I can see the `start-server` and change anything in there, but I am not able to go back.

This is information about my system:

[image: system info]

I already got ftp users, but I want them to connect to a specific location as I said before.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: i edited the following things in the config in /etc/vsftpd.conf
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftp.chroot_list
and maked a new home directory but and its worked but i still can go back up to all my files i want this acces to be disable i saw pepole tell to allow "chroot_local_user=YES
" i did but still the same
usermod --home /home/user username

Comment: I have to get help i have ftp user that connect directly to my location but i dont want this user to be able to go back (filezilla vsftpd)  if he is clicking the .. folder then he can go back please help